# Vue3 cannot import `@cornerstone/tools` , with error `ICRPolySeg.wasm`

Tags: vue.js, webpack, cornerstone

In Vue 3 , I cannot import `@cornerstone/tools`

```
import * as cornerstoneTools from "@cornerstonejs/tools";

window.cornerstoneTools = cornerstoneTools;
```

Above will meet bug:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@icr/polyseg-wasm/dist/ICRPolySeg.wasm 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'a' in '/Users/XXX/tmu/vue-cornerstone/node_modules/@icr/polyseg-wasm/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/@icr/polyseg-wasm/dist/index.js 2:0-37 17:17-21
 @ ./node_modules/@cornerstonejs/tools/dist/esm/workers/polySegConverters.js 10:0-43 34:25-35 62:30-40 130:30-40
 @ ./node_modules/@cornerstonejs/tools/dist/esm/stateManagement/segmentation/polySeg/registerPolySegWorker.js 12:11-14:6
 @ ./node_modules/@cornerstonejs/tools/dist/esm/stateManagement/segmentation/polySeg/computeAndAddRepresentation.js 7:0-64 10:2-23
 @ ./node_modules/@cornerstonejs/tools/dist/esm/stateManagement/segmentation/polySeg/Surface/computeAndAddSurfaceRepresentation.js 2:0-77 6:9-36
 @ ./node_modules/@cornerstonejs/tools/dist/esm/stateManagement/segmentation/polySeg/index.js 1:0-98 5:0-154
 @ ./node_modules/@cornerstonejs/tools/dist/esm/stateManagement/segmentation/index.js 13:0-44 14:0-304
 @ ./node_modules/@cornerstonejs/tools/dist/esm/index.js 10:0-63 14:0-1252
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 2:0-57 15:30-46
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 1:0-189 1:0-189 1:190-368 1:190-368
 @ ./src/App.vue 2:0-54 3:0-49 3:0-49 6:49-55
 @ ./src/main.js 2:0-28 3:10-13
```

where the `package.json` is

```
"@babel/plugin-transform-class-static-block": "^7.24.1",
"@cornerstonejs/core": "1.66.9",
"@cornerstonejs/tools": "1.66.9",
```

the `vue.config.js` is

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
  experiments: {
    syncWebAssembly: true
    asyncWebAssembly: true,
    }
  },
})
```

the `babel.config.js` is

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ],
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-class-static-block"]
}
```

---

I don't know why `node_modules/@icr/polyseg-wasm/dist/ICRPolySeg.wasm` will print the bug.

In cornerstone official example : https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone3D/blob/main/utils/demo/helpers/initCornerstoneDICOMImageLoader.js#L7

The below code can work

```
import * as cornerstoneTools from '@cornerstonejs/tools';

window.cornerstoneTools = cornerstoneTools;
```

---

The bug can reproduce in the repo : https://github.com/tkt9k2562/vue-cornerstone

Comment: move project to vite

Comment: @TachibanaShin
Magic! It really work with Vite , with `<script setup> window.cornerstoneTools = cornerstoneTools; window.cornerstoneTools = cornerstoneTools;</script>`